# Hide inherited properties on a class/interface?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, .net-4.0, interface

I was wondering if there is a way to hide inherited properties on sub types in C#, something like this for instance:

```
public interface ISupplierLogin : ISupplier
{
    [Obsolete]
    new string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    new long ABN { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    new DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
}

public interface ISupplier
{
    bool TradeOnly { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Business Name")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length of business name is 25 characters.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Australian Business Number")]
    [ABNValidator(ErrorMessage="The ABN you entered does not appear to be valid.")]
    long ABN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage="The username you entered does not appear to be valid. (a-z & 0-9)")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length of username is 25 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length of password must be between 8 and 12 characters long.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Registered")]
    DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
}
```

Where I want to inherit my validation attributes in my view model, but only for two properties.

Is there anyway to achieve what I am trying to do neatly?

Thanks.

Comment: You could make the base member virtual, then override it with `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the idea of inheritance: Basically when you have two classes `A` and `B`, and `B` is an exension of `A`, `B` will **inherit** all non-private elements of `A`; this is no different if you were using an interace and a class, two interfaces, etc.

Therefore in my opinion you should **only use** inheritance if you implement **all fields**, else you kind of defeat the purpose of inheritance and you're not following the object oriented principles.

What you *can do* however (not the best option, but it is possible) is use:

```
thow new NotImplementedException();
```

This make show to the end-programmer that he/she cannot use this property, as his or her application will throw an exception in the debugging stage.

Similarly you can use `[Obsolete(..., true)]`, which will make the compiler throw an error on compiling; *note* the second parameter is set to `true`. *Also*, you can use `[Browsable(false)]` to hide it in IntelliSense, but this will still allow use of this property.

---

You can add this to a property, which will effectively disable most usages of your property. It will **not** actually hide it in the sense you want, but it does show a developer to ignore it.

```
[Bindable(false)]
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

As far as actually hiding it goes, I don't think there is a possibility for that.

Comment: Yes that is the concept of inheritance, however I am trying to hide the properties from reflection, as to avoid errors when model binding. So I am really asking how to achieve something 'like' inheritance in this situation, but where I am hiding properties instead of adding them.

Comment: Well that's the whole problem with inheritance, there is no 'hiding' properties, only extending, but let me edit the answer with something I've found on the internet a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this previous question will give you the answers you seek.

[How to hide an inherited property in a class without modifying the inherited class (base class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875401/how-to-hide-an-inherited-property-in-a-class-without-modifying-the-inherited-clas)