# Hide Inheritance in WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Is it possible to hide class inheritance in a web service WSDL? eg, is there an attribute I can add to a class so that all inherited fields/properties will appear directly on that class in the WSDL?

I have an existing web service and I would like to modify existing classes to inherit from each other, however I do not want to risk making any breaking changes to the WSDL.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806552/how-to-hide-type-inheritance-in-net-xml-web-services-wsdl) only I do not need to hide the base class.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  If you are creating your WSDL from the regular tools, it mostly ignores inheritance unless you provide instructions otherwise

Comment: You should add an example of the issue you are facing. Also, what framework are you using? WCF?