# Why does my re-implemented method retain the base class' attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two classes, `RichString` and `RequiredRichString`.  In `RequiredRichString`, I'm re-implementing the `Value` property with the 'new' keyword.  If I reflect the attributes on `Value` on `RequiredRichString`, I only get `Required`, but after testing posting markup multiple times, `AllowHtml` is still taking effect.

```
public class RichString
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RequiredRichString : RichString
{
    [Required]
    new public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In short: Why does ASP.NET still acknowledge the `AllowHtml` attribute when I re-implement the `Value` property with `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the flag set:

`[AttributeUsage(Inherited=true)]`

Then the attribute will be inherited.

But you can subclass the `Attribute` to your needs, ie `MyAttribute(Enabled = true)` in the base class and `MyAttribute(Enabled = false)` in the new implementation. For instance...

```
[AttributeUsage(Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=true, Inherited=true)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute() { }

    public void SomethingTheAttributeDoes()
    {
        if (this.Enabled) this._DoIt)();
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    [MyAttribute(Enabled = true)]
    public double SizeOfIndexFinger { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedObject : MyObject
{
    [MyAttribute(Enabled = false)]
    public new double SizeOfIndexFinger { get; set; }
}
```

Note this answer: [How to hide an inherited property in a class without modifying the inherited class (base class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875401/how-to-hide-an-inherited-property-in-a-class-without-modifying-the-inherited-cla) - it seems maybe you can achieve what you want by using method overriding rather than hiding.

I can understand why you would think otherwise for a `new` property, but my understanding is that `new` is about *providing a new implementation*, often in the form of a new storage mechanism (a new backing field for instance) rather than changing the visible *interface* of the subclass. `Inherited=true` is a promise that subclasses will inherit the `Attribute`. It makes sense or at least it could be argued that only a superseding `Attribute` should be able to break this promise.