# How to block access to some properties like Location, when the class inherits from user control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I want to create MyOwnTabControl and give access from outside this class to change some properties in TAbPage. Class MyOwnTabControl contains array of object of class MyTabPage, which is also created by me. MyTabPage class also inherits from user control. So the point is that when I want to give access to change backcolor  of object of this class but I don't want to give other programmers change the value of Location (both these properties are defined in UserControl class) from outside the class. How I can do it?

Comment: Location applies to MyOwnTabControl just the same way as it applied to any control.  It's location may always be 0,0 but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Various approaches with pros/cons in [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1875401/2330053).